# How do I add google analytics code in my landing pages made using RefineryCMS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-analytics, content-management-system, refinerycms

I have one RefineryCMS application where I want to add option for creating landing pages. And in these individual landing pages there must be provision for adding unique google analytics code. But i am not able to do it as this CMS provides option for adding only one google analytics code for the entire site.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Since Google Analytics is a JS script, you'll make use of `yield` and `content_for` rails helpers

in your head partial add this where you want the Google analytics code to be:

```
<%= yield :analytics %>
```

in your respective landing page(at the very top), add this:

```
<% content_for :analytics do %>

***Google analytics script goes here***

<% end %>
```

that should help